# there is a way to save a pdf file with a path folder name of the excel file+vba?

Tags: excel, vba

New in this. What I want to do is the following. I have an excel file that are save in "X folder" (always different), I have to print a pdf from that file and I need to name as "XFolder+VICPDFQuote", I need to save this pdf in the same folder where the excel is. I have the following code but I missing something as the file is saved in a different folder:

```
' Print_quote Macro

ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlPortrait
    Worksheets("Quote").PageSetup.PrintArea = "$H$6:$P$133"

        Sheets(Array("Cov", "Quote", "T&C VIC")).Select
    strFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFile


   ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
     ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & FolderName & "VICPDFQuote", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

 Sheets("Quote").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: What's `FolderName`?

Comment: FolderName should reflect ThisWorkbook.Path, but as valid filename(no /\<>:?*" )? Then`FolderName =Replace(Replace(ThisWorkbook.Path,"\","!"),":","!")`using ! as separator-

Comment: the folder name is always different.i have an excel file name pear project located in "apples folder". The pdf file needs to be named "Apples VICPDFQuote"

Comment: So just store first parent folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get folder name, that contains the file use FileSystemObject

```vb
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim NewFileName As String
    NewFileName = .GetFile(ThisWorkbook.FullName).ParentFolder.Name & " VICPDFQuote.pdf"
End With
```

Comment: hi, thanks but it doesn't work. Name the pdf as false

Comment: Show result and`Workbook.FullName`.You can just replace your`FolderName`in code with`CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(ThisWorkbook.FullName).ParentFolder.Name`

Comment: You're welcome! You missed to assign my new varibl`NewFileName` to your pdf export?